# xampp - won't show certain page - it shows blank page

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

So, I have used xampp since 2 months ago with no problem.
I run my site on localhost.
I can run localhost/phpmyadmin just fine.
Six hours ago, I still could run my **every** web pages on my browser perfectly.
but now, I can run the *index*, *contact-us* page, but I can't run my *catalogue* page.

I use codeigniter btw.

Strange, xampp can display index page (which also IS php page), but when I run catalogue page, it shows BLANK page, nothing, even on the page source, nothing. I even tried to do this: on my controller for catalogue page, I change the code for function index from:

```
function index {
 $this->load->view('catalogue_pages/view_catalogue',$this->data);
}
```

to

```
function index {
$this->load->view('testpage');
}
```

which, testpage.php is just a dummy echo 'hello world'
but it still doesn't work now. But it WAS running smoothly 6 hours ago.

Any ideas how to solve this?

i'm using xampp v3.2.1
windows 7 32bit

Comment: do you have any errors? error reporting ON?

Comment: Function names need to be suffixed with `()` if there are no parameters.

Comment: Got the same problem in 2017 ! Does someone founds the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have an error? try turning error reporting on

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: nope. I tried it already. it is still empty, whether it be on view_catalogue.php or the dummy (testpage.php) file. the page source is also still blank. fyi, for the past 6 hours, I didn't touch the catalogue page at all.